# Create a variable from domains input file

Tags: go, variables, input, var

I am trying to create a variable in Go that will take the beginning of the domains input (before the '.com' or '.net') from my list "Domains.txt"

The variable I am trying to create is "%DomainName%", if one of the Domain inside Domains.txt is 'qwerty.com' then %DomainName% := qwerty

Your help would be very appreciated,

Thank you.

---

I tried the read() function and also the scan() function without success.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the strings.Split() function to achieve this. Here's an example code snippet:

```
···

package main

import (
"fmt"
"strings"
)

func main() {
    domain := "qwerty.com"
    parts := strings.Split(domain, ".")
    domainName := parts[0]
    fmt.Println(domainName)
}

···
```

This code splits the domain string at the ".", and assigns the first part to the domainName variable. Check the https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split documentation for more information on the strings.Split() function.